# Create background activity on Samsung smartphone that will run for hours

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create some activities that run in the background, so that the samsung system will put those activities in the background activities list as in the picture.
[Samsung background activities list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH0qd.png)

I'm using Kotlin to develop this and I'm still at beginner level with Kotlin. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: https://medium.com/make-android/start-android-activity-or-service-from-the-background-689f49167d80